# How can I get TracePrint to treat certain functions as atomic?

Tags: debugging

Consider the following example:

```
In[1]:= f[x_]:=x+1;g[x_]:=f[2x]

In[2]:= TracePrint[g[1]]
 g[1]
  g
  1
 f[2 1]
  f
  2 1
   Times
   2
   1
  2
 f[2]
 2 + 1
  Plus
  2
  1
 3

Out[2]= 3
```

So far, so good. However I'd now like to instruct TracePrint to treat evaluation of `f` as atomic, that is not to print the intermediate steps of evaluating `f[2]`, so that the next line after `f[2]` would be `3` (but without excluding any other lines). My first idea was to just make `f` read protected:

```
In[3]:= SetAttributes[f,ReadProtected]

In[4]:= TracePrint[g[1]]
 g[1]
  g
  1
 f[2 1]
  f
  2 1
   Times
   2
   1
  2
 f[2]
 2 + 1
  Plus
  2
  1
 3

Out[4]= 3
```

As you can see, the inner working of `f` is still traced. However the attribute is otherwise honoured:

```
In[5]:= ?f
Global`f

Attributes[f] = {ReadProtected}
```

Another thing which does not work is

```
TracePrint[g[1],Except[_f]]
```

which again gives the complete trace.

So how do I instruct `TracePrint` to treat the function `f` as atomic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe

```
  TracePrint[g[1], TraceOff -> f]
```

?

Comment: They should *really* mention that option on the `TracePrint` help page!

Comment: @celtschk, couldn't agree more.

Comment: @celtschk The documentation of `Trace` has a whole list of options. The documentation of `TracePrint` says (among other things): "TracePrint does not support the TraceBackward option of Trace." which (rather vaguely, I agree) implies other options of `Trace` should work. See also this [tracing overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TracingEvaluation.html)

Comment: Don't forget `TraceInternal` a boolean flag (previously documented, but not anymore) which will allow tracing into the internal functions not normally traceable.